# What is the best way to convert a chunk into writable stream for FFMPEG or FS.write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, mediarecorder, node.js-fs

I have a chunk of data and I use `const blob = new Blob(chunks)` to make into a `blob` and from a `blob` into an `arrayBuffer` with `Buffer.from(await blob.arrayBuffer())` and then I make a `stream` from `buffer` with `Readable.from(buffer);`

However the whole process seems to be painstaking and I have run into some serious memory and garbage collection issues while using buffers. Is there anyway I can get a stream directly from the chunk or the blob not having to go through any buffers and make into a file?